# Not able to Upload video files using ajaxfileupload control in asp.net c#, results into error with red block

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using ajax toolkit from [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/)

I can upload .jpg, .jpeg, .txt, .doc, but not able to upload .wmv file..ie not able to upload videos file.

Below is my code

**File.aspx**

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" OnUploadComplete="AjaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete"
    runat="server"/>
```

**File.cs**

```
protected void AjaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Generate file path
            string filePath = "~/Images/" + e.FileName;

            // Save upload file to the file system
            AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", ex.Message.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

I want to know where i am wrong... what i have to add in the code so that i can upload video files

Comment: What is the error/exception text you get?

Comment: i am not able to insert images... so not able to show you error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Pritesh have you check your file size.
by default 4 mb  file upload avail in asp.net 
If problem of size then add below line in Web config file.

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="11264" />
</system.web>
```

value change as per ur req.